# When I am trying to save raw sensor data in json file it is writing json array in the file multiple times instead of one json array

Tags: android, android-studio

I made an app to get raw sensor data. Now I want to save it in json file. The problem is when I am saving the sensor's data for example light sensor data the file is containing multiple json arrays instead of one. Also for every new jsonArray in order the jsonObject inside it is repeating itself.
This is the output that I am getting:

```json
[{"light value":114.2565}]
[{"light value":114.798004},{"light value":114.798004}]
[{"light value":116.4225},{"light value":116.4225},{"light value":116.4225}]
[{"light value":117.50551},{"light value":117.50551},{"light value":117.50551},{"light value":117.50551}].....so on
```

The output that I want is :

```json
[{"light value":114.2565},{"light value":114.798004},{"light value":116.4225},{"light value":117.50551}.....so on ]
```

This is the part of code where I think can be problem:

```kotlin
 

    override fun onSensorChanged(p0: SensorEvent?) {
            if (p0?.sensor?.type == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT) {
                val lightText: TextView = findViewById(R.id.light_Sensor)
                lightText.text = "Light Value  = ${p0!!.values[0]}"
    
                jsonObject.put("light value",p0!!.values[0])
                jsonArray.put(jsonObject)
                var userString : String = jsonArray.toString()
                bufferedWriter.write(userString)
            }
        }
```

This is the whole code for your reference:

```kotlin
package com.example.sensor

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.hardware.Sensor
import android.hardware.SensorEvent
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener
import android.hardware.SensorManager
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.io.BufferedInputStream
import java.io.BufferedWriter
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileWriter
import java.lang.NullPointerException

class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity(),SensorEventListener {
    lateinit var sensorManager: SensorManager
    lateinit var lightSensor: Sensor
    lateinit var jsonArray:JSONArray
    lateinit var jsonObject: JSONObject
    lateinit var file : File
     var userString: String? =null
    lateinit var filewriter:FileWriter
    lateinit var bufferedWriter: BufferedWriter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
       
        //Initializing the variables
        file = File(applicationContext.externalCacheDir, "user.json")
        filewriter = FileWriter(file)
         bufferedWriter = BufferedWriter(filewriter)
        jsonArray = JSONArray()
        jsonObject = JSONObject()
        //getting sensor services
        sensorManager= getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
        if(sensorManager!=null) {
            //registering listener the sensor
            lightSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT)
            sensorManager.registerListener(this,lightSensor,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL)

        }else  Toast.makeText(this,"no sensor detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)

    }

    override fun onSensorChanged(p0: SensorEvent?) {
        if (p0?.sensor?.type == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT) {
            val lightText: TextView = findViewById(R.id.light_Sensor)
            lightText.text = "Light Value  = ${p0!!.values[0]}"

            jsonObject.put("light value",p0!!.values[0])
            jsonArray.put(jsonObject)
            var userString : String = jsonArray.toString()
            bufferedWriter.write(userString)
        }
    }

    override fun onAccuracyChanged(p0: Sensor?, p1: Int) {
    }

   
    override fun onDestroy() {
        bufferedWriter.close()
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this)
        super.onDestroy()
    }
 }
```

Comment: You should format your JSON, I don’t really see any structural difference between the output you want and the output you have

Comment: @Rafsanjani I edited the question . Please see the code again.